# I need to add some string to specific parts of a txt file in python

Tags: python, file

Let's say I have a .txt file with tests in it like such :

> 1
>
> Question example?
>
> A) answer B) other answer C) another answer
>
> 2
>
> Another question example?
>
> A) good answer B) decent answer C) bad one
>
> 3
>
> Third question example?

...And another 300 questions

And I have a list of correct answers for these questions like:
`['B', 'A', 'C', 'A' ... ' D']` (All in order)

I want to modify the text file so each answer on this list would be next to the number of its question like:

> 1B
>
> Question example?
>
> ...
>
> 2A
>
> Another question example?
>
> ...

Etc.

I've tried many things but I can't really get it properly

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately this is not a code-writing site. You stated that you've "tried many things" but it would help us to help you if you would include details about your most recent attempt, the code you tried, and what went wrong to make a [mcve]

Comment: Hi Isa, welcome. Do you think you could give us a look at some of the code that you tried already? We try to fix code here at Stack Overflow so if you could give us a sample of the code we'll do our best to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

So, the first thing to come to mind is this:

```
listOfLines = yourInputAsAString.split("\n")
for i in range(len(listOfLines)):
    b = i*3;
    listOfLines[b] = str(i)+ listOfAnswers[i]
for line in listOfLines:
    outputfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way, assuming the order and number of answers is correct:

```
answers = ['B', 'A', 'C']

with open('answers.txt') as in_file, open('answers2.txt','w') as out_file:
  idx = 0
  for line in in_file:
    if line.strip().isdigit():
      out_file.write(line.strip() + answers[idx])
      idx += 1
    else:
      out_file.write(line)
```